# Why are some memory addresses reported constant while others change?

Tags: r, memory, memory-address

I've been trying to keep track of various objects in memory using `data.table::address` or `.Internal(address())`, but have noticed that some objects return the same address every time, while others are almost always different.  What is going on here?

I've noticed that addresses of objects like lists (data.tables, data.frames, etc) remain constant (as reported by these functions), whereas if I try to report the address by `[` into a list, ie `address(lst[1])` I get different results nearly everytime.  On the other hand `lst[[1]]` returns the same value, and the addresses of constants like `address(pi)` remain constant whereas `address(1)` is volatile.  Why is this happening?

```
## Create some data.tables of different sizes and plot the addresses
library(data.table)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for (i in 2:5) {
    dat <- data.table(a=1:10^i)
    ## Constants
    addr1 <- address(dat)
    addr2 <- address(dat[[1]])
    addr3 <- address(dat$a)  # same as addr2
    ## Vary
    addrs <- replicate(5000, address(dat[1]))
    plot(density(as.integer(as.hexmode(addrs))), main=sprintf("N: %g", nrow(dat)))
    abline(v=as.integer(as.hexmode(c(addr1, addr2, addr3))), col=1:3, lwd=2, lty=1:3)
    legend("topleft", c("dat", "dat[[1]]", "dat$a"), col=1:3, lwd=2, lty=1:3)
}
```

Here are some examples of what I'm talking about with different sized data.tables.  They are just densities of the results from `address(dat[1])` (converted to an integer), and the lines correspond to the constant addresses of the data.table.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the full answer (you'd have to study the C code), but some suggestions. The functions `[[` and `$` return a single list element. However, `[` returns a list containing one or more list elements, which means these elements are copied. There might be optimizations possible that avoid these copies in specific circumstances, but that topic is above my pay grade.

Comment: Are you looking for the why scalar-indexing "list"s with `"["` will copy objects unlike `"[["` or how is this happening? Only `"[["` and only for "list"-like objects seems to not allocate a new SEXP to be returned and, so, no copying takes place extracting subsets. Also, unlike, a created variable (like "pi"), typing "1" creates a new object each time.

Comment: @TheTime : If you create two variables with a value"a" you have STRSXPs; the caching involves CHARSXPs which are unaccessible. E.g.see `straddr = inline::cfunction(sig = c(x = "character"), body = ' Rprintf("%p\\n", x); ')`; `charaddr = inline::cfunction(sig = c(x = "character"), body = ' Rprintf("%p\\n", STRING_ELT(x, 0)); ')`. `x ="a"; y = "a"`. `straddr(x); straddr(y); charaddr(x);charaddr(y)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I can replicate your results, so I did a bit of an investigation and dived through some code.

When you access the first member of `dat` using `dat[1]` you are actually creating a slice made from the `list` in `data[[1]]` or `dat$a`.  To take a slice, R first copies the list and then returns the slice you want.

So - basically - you see what you see because the `[]` syntax for indexing returns a slice containing the first element of `dat` ***which is a copy of `dat$a`, which will be at an arbitrary memory location.***

The `[[]]` syntax returns a reference to the actual list that is the column in your `data.table` or `data.frame` and hence its address is invariant (or at least it is until you change a member of that list).

This could be confusing, because of course doing `dat[1] = 6` or similar will alter the value(s) of the list in your data structure.  However, if you look at `address(dat[[1]])` before and after making such a change, you will notice that in fact the reference is now to a different list (the copy) e.g.

```
> dat <- data.table(a=1:10000)
> dat
           a
    1:     1
    2:     2
    3:     3
    4:     4
    5:     5
   ---      
 9996:  9996
 9997:  9997
 9998:  9998
 9999:  9999
10000: 10000
> address(dat[[1]])
[1] "000000000CF389D8"
> address(dat[[1]])
[1] "000000000CF389D8"
> dat[1] = 100
> address(dat[[1]])
[1] "000000000D035B38"
> dat
           a
    1:   100
    2:     2
    3:     3
    4:     4
    5:     5
   ---      
 9996:  9996
 9997:  9997
 9998:  9998
 9999:  9999
10000: 10000
>
```

Looking at the source code for `data.frame` (rather than `data.table`), the code that does the slice indexing (`[]`) [is here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L543), whereas the direct indexing (`[[]]`) [is here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L694).  You can see that the latter is simpler and to cut a long story short, the former returns a copy.  If you change a slice directly (e.g. `dat[1] = 5`), there is some [logic here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L717) that handles ensuring that the data frame now references the updated copy.